# how to get the 5th latest entry from mysql

Tags: mysql

Assuming i have a mysql table that after sorted, looks like this:-

- 20 Jan, 2015
- 19 Jan, 2015
- 18 Jan, 2015
- ....
- 2 Jan, 2015
- 1 Jan, 2015

If i want to get only the latest 5 data, i can do

```
from table select * LIMIT 5
```

... and this will return rows

- 20 Jan, 2015
- 19 Jan, 2015
- 18 Jan, 2015
- 17 Jan, 2015
- 16 Jan, 2015

Is there a way to just get the row of

- 16 Jan, 2015
  ?

Comment: SELECT * from table order by datum_field ASC LIMIT1

Comment: @BerndBuffen , that would have returned me 5 rows. I want just 1 row, which is the last from 'LIMIT 5"

Comment: ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1

Comment: `LIMIT 4,1` - skip 4 and select one after them. And always specify the `ORDER BY`

Comment: SELECT * FROM (YOUR QUERY HERE) x ORDER BY ... LIMIT. (Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless).

Comment: thats y i love bash ;) ---  `> sort  | head -5 | tail -1`

Comment: Beautiful, @jkavalik !!!! That's exactly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * from table Order By DESC LIMIT 4,1;`